# java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have changed the code in few model classes from field accessors to property accessors and also changed from List to Set because order was not important. Following is my entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TPYP_GAME")
public class Game extends AbstractGeneratedIdEntity{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1390767030654384142L;

    private static final String GAME_FIELD = "GAME";

    private GameypeEnum gameTypeEnum;    
    private Set<GameCode> gameCodes;    

    @Transient
    public GameTypeEnum getGameTypeEnum() {
        return gameTypeEnum;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = GAME_FIELD, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<GameCode> getGameCodes() {
        return gameCodes;
    }

    public void setGameTypeEnum(GameTypeEnum gameTypeEnum) {
        this.gameTypeEnum = gameTypeEnum;
    }

    public void setGameCodes(Set<GameCode> gameCodes) {
        this.gameCodes = gameCodes;
    }
```

I debugged into the source code and found that it is throwing following exception when committing transaction after getting the data from the repository.

```
 org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction;
 nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
 javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction java.util.HashSet 
 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection
```

I am not sure how to fix it. What am I missing?

---

Client code:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true) 
    public List<Game> getGames(String nameContains, Long pageSize){ 
    if(!nameContains.isEmpty() && pageSize !=null){ 
    return repository.findAll(nameIsLike(nameContains), constructPageSpecification(pageSize)).getContent(); }
    else{ if(pageSize != null){ 
    return repository.findAll(null, constructPageSpecification(pageSize)).getContent(); }
    else if(!nameContains.isEmpty()){ 
    return repository.findAll(nameIsLike(nameContains)); }else{ return repository.findAll(); 
}
 }
     }
```

Comment: What's the exception that's being thrown?  Please provide a stacktrace.  Your question title mentions "java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection", but there's no mention of it in your actual question.

Comment: show us your client code

Comment: I have edited my question and provided more information.

Comment: The problem may be related to this:  https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5862

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `setGameCodes` is replacing a `Set` read from the database with a newly created `HashSet` instead of adding to or removing from the existing one which causes problems when you try to commit changes back to the DB.

Perhaps `setGameCodes` should do

```
this.gameCodes.clear();
this.gameCodes.addAll(gameCodes);
```

instead of

```
this.gameCodes = gameCodes;
```

Comment: I don't think so that is the case because it is happening before the control returns back to my code. It is failing (throwing exception) right after it gets the data from the repository and when it tries to commit the transaction.

org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl:commit()